# Show a default text in a jTextField

Tags: java, swing, default, jtextfield

I want to have a default "$ (dollar sign)" in my textfield which should not disappear even if there's another output to be shown and even if I need to input something in the same textfield.

nevermindddd, sorted it out on my own hehehe :DDDDD

Answer (score 2):

If you are showing something to the text field just add the $ at the beginning of the thing you want to show.

If you want to have it always be there on the input you can try something like this:

```
textBox.setText("$ ");
textBox.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    try {
        if(textBox.getText().charAt(0) == "$".charAt(0) && textBox.getText().charAt(1) == " ".charAt(0)) {
            // there is a $ at the beginning
        } else {
            // there is no $ and we have to insert it
            textBox.setText("$ " + textBox.getText());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        textBox.setText("$ ");
    }
});
```